# Importing data to an array from db file in android

Tags: android, import

I have made a db file in sqlitestudio. I have saved the db file in assets folder of my application. Now I want to get data from that db file and store it in an array or list and use it in my app. Please help!

Comment: So what's the problem you are getting and where exactly?

Comment: I know how to use the sqlitehelper classes. But i dont know how to import an external database from db file and use data in it. @InnocentKiller

Comment: you cannot access it from assets folder directly, you. need to copy it to yours app data storage for example

Comment: How can i do that sir? @pskink

Comment: http://www.google.com/m?q=java+how+to+copy+file&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new